# How to use Laravel queue listen in Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, queue

When running on localhost, I use:

`php artisan queue:listen database`

which listens and acts as queue. This works fine until I want to Dockerize my Laravel app. I have already done this, so cannot run the command so that container would have queue listener.

I read that I can do the following:

`docker exec -t (containername) php artisan queue:listen`

I would like to find another way of doing this, because if container dies and restarts itself, this command won't get executed, and I can't just watch when container dies so that I can do it by hand. I want an automatic way. each container who starts has to have this command automatically running. I tried in Dockerfile, but doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 6):

Create a new service as bellow and run it on the same image.

Here is my `docker-composer.yml` file, This will help to run the queues in **AWS Fargate** environments as well

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  www:
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    image: php-laravel:latest
    ports: 
        - "8008:80"
    volumes:
        - ./src:/var/www/html/
    networks:
        - default
  php-queue:
    restart: always
    image: php-laravel:latest
    command: php artisan queue:work
    volumes:
        - ./src:/var/www/html/
volumes:
    default:
```

Comment: exec: php artisan queue:work: not found

Answer (score 2):

Create another container with the same image.

Here is my `docker-composer.yml` file

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    php:
        build:
            args:
                user: sammy
                uid: 1000
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfiles/php.dockerfile
        image: sarah-php
        container_name: sarah-php
        user: 'sammy'
        restart: unless-stopped
        working_dir: /var/www/
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/
        networks:
            - sarah
        depends_on:
            - redis
            - mysql

    queue:
        image: sarah-php
        container_name: sarah-queue
        restart: always
        working_dir: /var/www/
        command: php artisan queue:work
        depends_on:
            - php
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        networks:
            - sarah
```

It should be noted that for the `command` to work correctly, you need to set `work_dir` first.

Answer (score 1):

To execute a command after startup, add in your Dockerfile `RUN cd /my/project/root && php artisan queue:listen`

Also, you can use [vessel](https://vessel.shippingdocker.com/) to work with Docker, it's already preconfigured for Laravel so that you can simply do something like `./vessel artisan <cmd>`

Comment: I've tried `RUN php artisan queue:listen &` with and without `&`. In both case, they don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is a correct way. But I am doing it for a long time and it's working well for me.

Go to the project folder.
Run `php artisan queue:listen`

Before running this command add the current user to the `www-data` group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use container inheritance in docker-compose. In my case "app" container implements php:7.4.10-fpm. If you run the "php artisan queue:work" command inside "app", then it will not work (I don’t know why, I think because the command hangs the terminal process), but if inherited, then the command is executed conditionally in a separate terminal and does not break anything

```
app:
 &base-app
 build:
  context: './docker/main/app'
  container_name: ${DOCKER_COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_app

worker:
 <<: *base-app
 container_name: ${DOCKER_COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_worker
 command: php artisan queue:work
```

Answer (score -1):

You should create supervisorctl command.

[how to install and create supervisorctl command?](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps)

[laravel docs about supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#supervisor-configuration)

my laravel-worker.conf file:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=docker exec -t <docker container id (you can find it with command: docker ps)> php artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3 --max-time=3600
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
;user=root
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/itsoft/it-software/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

Answer (score -2):

If you need to have more than a single worker, you can set it up with supervisor, as explained in the Laravel Queue Page https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#supervisor-configuration